# Angular 10 | Loading js script in app.component.html if environment production false

Tags: html, angular

I try to load a js file, which should trigger only in dev mode.

I have this code in my `app.component.html`:

```
<p *ngIf="!environment"> works </p>
<script *ngIf="!environment" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script *ngIf="!environment" src="/src/assets/js/my.js"></script>
```

`environment` is `false`.

Note that it works fine for the `<p>` tag, but not for the `<script>` tags, why?

**EDIT**

To clarify, the script tags do NOT load, but they should, because `environment` is `false`. I dont get any errors, nothing. They are simply not there, but the `p` tag does load.

Comment: here is ur answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264308/why-does-ngif-not-remove-script-tags-from-my-code

Comment: @sagat while that question is similar, I don't believe it's the same as this one. That one is for AngularJS version 1, so the behaviour could've changed. The problem "symptoms" are also exactly the opposite from OP's, in that question they are asking why the script tags *are* loaded _regardless_ of ng-if, while here in OP's question they are *not* loaded at all.

Comment: in the question he is saying that it always loads no matter if its false or true. So the answer from the upper thread should be right. Cause this is Browser behavior I think this would not have changed with angular 2+. BUT, I might be wrong about that.

Comment: @sagat The scripts do NOT load

Comment: Ahhh okay. That was my mistake then :) Srry for confusion. I didnt think about !environment. But how come u only ask for environment and not environment.production?

Comment: @sagat environment is environment.production, it looks like that in the .ts file: `environment = environment.production`

Comment: Okay, then this might be a helpful answer for ur question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088996/adding-script-tags-in-angular-component-template Also read the question and got to the github link

Comment: Same principle here, but loading script file instead of script content: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61205045/1160794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be done in the `component.ts` file.

The special issue here is that my `my.js` file depends on the `jquery.min.js` file, which means I need a callback.

The below example will work.

If you use `this.appendScript('assets/js/my.js')` in the callback it wont work, because the `this` does reference the wrong scope. If I find a solution, I will add it.

```
appendScript(src, callbackFunc) {
    var script = document.createElement('script'); 
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = callbackFunc;  
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.navigation.loadView(this.navigation.getView(1).name); // Init first view
  
  if (!environment.production) {
    this.appendScript('assets/js/jquery.min.js', function () {
      var script = document.createElement('script'); 
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'assets/js/my.js';  
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      //this.appendScript('assets/js/my.js');
    });
  }
```